# Router TP-Link TL-WDR4300 not Forwarding ports

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, local-area-network, tp-link

Although I configured the forwarding ports in my router they are closed.

I have a **TP-Link TL-WDR4300** router connected to my home network. I also have a **TP-Link TL-WA850RE** repeater working as a Wi-Fi extender.

1. Logged into the WDR4300
2. Navigated to **Forwarding** > **Virtual Servers**
3. Clicked on **Add New**:

   - **Service Port:** 80
   - **Internal Port:** 80
   - **IP Address:** 192.168.0.103 *(This is also reserved into the DHCP Server)*
   - **Protocol:** ALL
   - **Status:** Enabled
4. Clicked on **Save**
5. Just in case I rebooted the router.

These were the steps I did use to configure the ***Forwarding ports***, after all this I have checked several online Port checkers and the `port 80` is still closed.

Just in case I stopped my AV and Firewall, but nothing happened.

Any ideas what's stopping me from opening ports in the router?